# How to work with Firebase without allowing optional values

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, optional-parameters

I'm new to iOS development and I understand that allowing optional values when an object is initialized is not a 'good citizen' technique. That being said, I've read that it is good practice to always have values set, like this:

```
class Item{
    var name: String
    var color: String
    init(name: String, color: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
    }
}
```

This looks nice and tidy but how can I do something like that working with Firebase? Look what I've got so far:

```
private func loadPosts(){
    databaseHandle = ref.child("users/\(self.user.uid)/posts").observe(.value, with:{(snapshot) in
        var newPosts = [Post]()

        for itemSnapShot in snapshot.children {
            let post = Post(snapshot: itemSnapShot as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newPosts.append(post!)
        }
        self.posts = newPosts
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

This guy is placed in my PostsViewController where I have my table view. This is my model:

```
class Post {
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?
    var title: String?
    var answer: String?
    var contentUrl: String?
    var photoUrl: String?
    var createdAt: String?
    var feeling: String?
    var kind: String?
    var text: String?
    var uid: String?
    var measurements: Dictionary<String, String>?

    //MARK: Initialization
    init?(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot){
        ref = snapshot.ref

        let data = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, Any>

        title = data["title"]! as? String
        answer = data["answer"] as? String
        contentUrl = data["content_url"] as? String
        photoUrl = data["photo_url"] as? String
        createdAt = data["created_at"] as? String
        feeling = data["feeling"] as? String
        kind = data["kind"] as? String
        text = data["text"] as? String
        uid = data["uid"] as? String
        measurements = data["measurements"] as? Dictionary<String, String>
    }
}
```

I don't know exactly why but those question marks doesn't feel quite right and now and then I get some nil pointer error, which I think I should be able to avoid by using the 'good citizen' technique.

So, does anybody know how can I use Firebase following Swift best practices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you wish to allow the properties of your Post class to be nil or you don't.

If you do, that's fine. The code you posted allows any of them to be nil. You just need to safely access each property every time you need it.

If you don't, then don't make them optional. Then in your `init` you need to ensure none of the properties are set to `nil` by giving each a default if there is no value in the snapshot.

```
class Post {
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference
    var title: String
    var answer: String
    var contentUrl: String
    var photoUrl: String
    var createdAt: String
    var feeling: String
    var kind: String
    var text: String
    var uid: String
    var measurements: [String : String]

    //MARK: Initialization
    init?(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        if let data = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
            self.ref = snapshot.ref

            title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
            answer = data["answer"] as? String ?? ""
            contentUrl = data["content_url"] as? String ?? ""
            photoUrl = data["photo_url"] as? String ?? ""
            createdAt = data["created_at"] as? String ?? ""
            feeling = data["feeling"] as? String ?? ""
            kind = data["kind"] as? String ?? ""
            text = data["text"] as? String ?? ""
            uid = data["uid"] as? String ?? ""
            measurements = data["measurements"] as? [String : String] ?? [:]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Note how this ensures there is a proper snapshot. Note how a default value is set to each property if there is no value in the snapshot. Obviously you can assign any default you wish. I use the empty string as an example.

Even if you want to allow the properties to be `nil`, you should at least update your code to check for a valid snapshot like in the code above.

Of course you can have a combination where some properties can't be `nil` and some can. That's up to your needs.

Comment: thanks for your great explanation and good examples on how to work with optionals. I tried the code you provided me but I had to make some changes to make it work:
 - the question mark after FIRDataSnapshot: init?(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot?)
- [String : Any] rather than [String, Any]
- [String : String] ?? [:] rather than [String : String]:[:]

are those changes ok? if so, would you mind editing your answer so I can select as accepted?

Comment: Fixed (I think). Those were typos in my answer.

Comment: thats what I thought, you answered really quick :) what about the ? in init?(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot?) , can I place it there?

Comment: Which of the two `?` do you mean? The one after `init` should be there as my code is written. I see no need for a `?` after `FIRDataSnapshot`.

Comment: the second one. I dont know, xcode was raising an error and made me put the question mark there.

Comment: The code you posted didn't have a `?` there. It's certainly not needed for the code in my answer. Though I've never used Firebase. Is the problem on the next line with the `if let ref` part? Maybe the `ref` property of  `FIRDataSnapshot` isn't optional.

Comment: I dont know, but it seems to be working fine with the question mark there. I mean, the app is running and I also got the expected xcode behavior: I had to dele lots of ! through my code because forcing unwrapping was no longer necessary.

Comment: Turns out `ref` isn't optional so I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: awesome! it's fully working now! thanks again, specially for the great explanations!

Answer (score 0):

First it is fine for you to have optionals in your data model, as long as you assign value to it later on in the future.

I would recommend to use `ObserveSingleEvent()` and you should make use of completion handler to make it easy. If you don't know completion handler: [Link](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-three-ways-to-pass-data-from-model-to-controller-b47cc72a4336)

I recommend:

•  not to put database ref in your class model, and instead of using `Dictionary<String, String>?` just use `[String: AnyObject]?`

• make your post array public so that it can be accessed into the tableview.

Here's example:

```
class func getPosts(uid: String, _ completion: @escaping (_ posts: [Post]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    //update inside users node
    var posts = [Post]()
    Firebase.databaseRef.child("users").child(uid).child("posts").observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (dataSnapshot) in
        guard let postsDictionary = dataSnapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            completion(nil, nil)
            return
        }
        let n = postsDictionary.count
        for postDictionary in postsDictionary {
            let post = Post()

            post.userID = uid

            if let content = postDictionary.value["content"] as? String {
                post.content = content
            }
            if let imageURL = postDictionary.value["imageURL"] as? String {
                post.imageURL = imageURL
            }
            if let timeStamp = postDictionary.key as String! {
                if let date = timeStamp.convertToDate() {
                    post.timeStamp = date
                }
                post.postIdentifier = timeStamp
            }
            posts.append(post)

            if posts.count == n {
                // Sort the array by the newest post
                let sortedPosts = posts.sorted(by: { $0.timeStamp.compare($1.timeStamp) == .orderedDescending })
                completion(sortedPosts, nil)
            }
        }
    }) { (error) in
        completion(nil, error)
    }
}
```

Assigning to tableview be like:

```
getPosts(uid: Current.user.userID!) { (posts, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error.debugDescription)
            return
        }
        cell.label.text = posts[indexPath.item].content
```