# Initialize an object to take in optional values on Firebase with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, initializer

I'm comfortable with initializing objects in general but my method only seems to work when all parameters must exist on the database. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266409/how-to-work-with-firebase-without-allowing-optional-values) which works. But I now don't know how to initialize it with a nest array.

This is how I would normally initialise an object:

```
class User {

    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var summary: String?
    var groups = [Group]()
    var ref: DatabaseReference?
    var key: String

    init?(from snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]

        guard let firstName = snapshotValue?["firstName"] as? String, let lastName = snapshotValue?["lastName"] as? String, let summary = snapshotValue?["summary"] as? String else { return nil }

        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.summary = summary
        self.key = snapshot.key

        self.groups(snapshot: snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "groups"))

    }

    func groups(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for child in snapshot.children {
            guard let group = child as? DataSnapshot else { continue }
        }
    }
```

Comment: show also an example of what you want to use to initialize it.. this looks like it should work

Comment: It doesn't. Let's say I want the _summary_ to be `optional`. If I try and initialize it, it will not work as the parameters doesn't exist.

Comment: oh I get it now, give me a second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't make the optional properties a part of that guard (that's what prevents the execution to finish it:

```
init?(from snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]

    guard let firstName = snapshotValue?["firstName"] as? String,
          let lastName = snapshotValue?["lastName"] as? String else { return nil }

    self.firstName = firstName
    self.summary = snapshotValue?["summary"] as? String
    self.key = snapshot.key

    self.groups(snapshot: snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "groups"))

}
```

Optionally, you can use `if let` syntax:

```
if let summary = snapshotValue?["summary"] as? String {
    self.summary = summary
}
```

But in this case this is simpler:

```
self.summary = snapshotValue?["summary"] as? String
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.